# How to select all items in a Listbox and concatenate them in ASP.NET C# Webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

Right now I have

```
  String myString = listbox1.Text.ToString();
```

However this only returns only the 1st item, even  if I hit ctrl and select all of them.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an extension method, you can do this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(this ListItemCollection items)
    {
        return items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var selected = listbox1.Items.GetSelectedItems();
```

---

Now you can take the `IEnumerable<ListItem>` and convert that to a string array, then finally make it into a single string separated by semicolons, like this:

```
// Create list to hold the text of each list item
var selectedItemsList = new List<string>();

// Create list to hold the text of each list item
var selectedItemsList = selected.Select(listItem => listItem.Text).ToList();

// Build a string separated by comma
string selectedItemsSeparatedByComma = String.Join(",",
    selectedItemsList.ToArray());
```

Comment: hey so i tried the extension, but when I try to do the usage with var selected = listbox1.Items.GetSelectedItems(); the .GetSelectedItems(); does not work, any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Can you put a break point on `var selected = listbox1.Items.GetSelectedItems();` hover over `Items` and see what the count is. If it is zero, then that means your selected items are getting trashed by the `Page_Load` event.

Comment: it says System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection does not have a definition of GetSelectedItems. When I hover over Items, it just says Gets the collection of items in the list control.

Comment: @ShahinBenom - did you create the `Extensions` class, along with the extension method in it? Did you put this class in the same namespace as your code or somewhere else?

Comment: I put it in the same namespace, still the .GetSelected doesn't work, here is my full code, I will add it to the original

Comment: @ShahinBenom - the code you posted is using `GetSelected()`, but the extension method is named `GetSelectedItems()`, is that a typo in the code you posted?

Comment: Wait, sorry I was rushing to respond and made another mistake, I got it working. Thank you very much for the help Karl!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, WebForms ListBox doesn't have the SelectedItems property. However, you can do

```
listBox.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected);
```

That will give you the items you are looking for.

If you can't use LINQ, just do a foreach over listBox.Items, and do whatever you want when the item is Selected.

Comment: hey, sorry this is not working for me. As it says it can not convert to string, when I try String myString = listbox1.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected);
could you show me your alternate option as well, and how I could concatenate them with a ";". Thanks for the help.

Comment: Simple - `string.Join(";", listBox.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Name).ToArray())`